# How to refresh page in console mode

Tags: console

I am not able to refresh the console page by using the following syntax. If i click on the button nothing happens. pls help me out

```
    <!-- Page Name:Rforce_MyRMyD_Gigya_Page
Description:This inline visualforce page is used to set the values for the MyR/MyD fields based on the condition satisfied
Created by:Ramamoorthy Dakshinamoorthy
Date:08-03-2016 --> 

    <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="Rforce_MyRMyD_VFCx" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" >
    <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/33.0/integration.js" />
    <apex:form id="formId">
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!bIsRefreshPage}">
    <script>
    var a = '{!Account.id}';
    if (sforce.console.isInConsole()) {
    alert('a ===>' + a);
    sforce.console.getFocusedPrimaryTabId(a); 
    }
    else {
    window.top.location='/{!Account.id}';
    }
    </script>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:pageBlock rendered="true" >
    <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages> 
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2"   >
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.Rforce_MyRUserName}" ></apex:outputLabel>{!Account.MyRenaultID__c}
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.Rforce_MyDUserName}"></apex:outputLabel>{!Account.MyDaciaID__c}
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.Rforce_MyRAccountCreationDate}"></apex:outputLabel>{!Account.MYR_CreationDate__c}
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.Rforce_MyDAccountCreationDate}" ></apex:outputLabel>{!Account.MyD_CreationDate__c}
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.Rforce_MyRAccountStatus}"></apex:outputLabel>{!Account.MYR_Status__c}
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.Rforce_MyDAccountStatus}"></apex:outputLabel>{!Account.MyD_Status__c}
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.Rforce_MyRAccountStatusUpdateDate}"></apex:outputLabel>{!Account.MYR_Status_UpdateDate__c}
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.Rforce_MyDAccountStatusUpdateDate}"></apex:outputLabel>{!Account.MyD_Status_UpdateDate__c}
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.Rforce_MyRLastConnectionDate}" ></apex:outputLabel>{!Account.MyR_Last_Connection_Date__c}
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.Rforce_MyDLastConnectionDate}" ></apex:outputLabel>{!Account.MyD_Last_Connection_Date__c}
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputPanel >
               <apex:commandButton value="{!$Label.Rforce_ACC_CreateMyR}" action="{!createAccount}" disabled="{!bIsCreateMyRButtonShown}" rerender="formId">
                 <apex:param name="brand" assignTo="{!sBrandName}" value="Renault"/>               
               </apex:commandButton>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!resetPassword}" value="{!$Label.Rforce_ACC_Reset_MyR}" rerender="formId" disabled="{!bIsResetMyRButtonShown}">
                  <apex:param name="brand" assignTo="{!sBrandName}" value="Renault"/>                
                </apex:commandButton>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!resendActivationEmail}" value="{!$Label.Rforce_ACC_MyRActivation}" rerender="formId" disabled="{!bIsReactiveMyRButtonShown}">
                  <apex:param name="brand" assignTo="{!sBrandName}" value="Renault"/>                 
                </apex:commandButton> 
            </apex:outputPanel> 
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputPanel >
                <apex:commandButton value="{!$Label.Rforce_ACC_CreateMyD}" action="{!createAccount}" disabled="{!bIsCreateMyDButtonShown}" rerender="formId">
                  <apex:param name="brand" assignTo="{!sBrandName}" value="Dacia"/>          
                </apex:commandButton>      
                <apex:commandButton action="{!resetPassword}" value="{!$Label.Rforce_ACC_Reset_MyD}" rerender="formId" disabled="{!bIsResetMyDButtonShown}">
                  <apex:param name="brand" assignTo="{!sBrandName}" value="Dacia"/>   
                </apex:commandButton>  
                <apex:commandButton action="{!resendActivationEmail}" value="{!$Label.Rforce_ACC_MyDActivation}" rerender="formId" disabled="{!bIsReactiveMyDButtonShown}">
                  <apex:param name="brand" assignTo="{!sBrandName}" value="Dacia"/>
                </apex:commandButton> 
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>    
    </apex:form> 
    </apex:page>
```

In alert the account id is coming perfectly but the page is not refreshed !!!

Comment: Have you tried sample code?https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_refreshprimarytabbyid.htm

Comment: Please try sample code. If that works theres something wrong with your code